# É possível executar múltiplas queries numa única execução?

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo, phpmyadmin

Eu precisava de alguns dados de um banco de dados no mysql. Porém, os dados estavam em tabelas diferentes, logo, a solução mais óbvia era de filtrar usando as tabelas relacionais, com os respectivos índices. Mas eu não conheço muito de mysql, até tentei usar as tabelas relacionais no phpmyadmin, mas não soube como fazer.

O que fazer? Obviamente não ficaria de braços cruzados na frente do pc, logo tentei bolar uma solução com um script em PHP, já que sou mais familiarizado.
Eis o script:

```
<?php

function queryDB($user, $pass)
{
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foobar', $user, $pass);

    foreach($connect->query("SELECT id, titulo FROM produtos WHERE publicado > 0") as $produto)
    {
        print($produto['id'].' -> '.$produto['titulo'].'<br>');

        $id = $produto['id'];

        $assuntos = $connect->query("SELECT id_assunto FROM produtos_tem_assuntos WHERE id_produto = $id");

        foreach($assuntos as $assunto_id)
        {
            foreach($connect->query("SELECT titulo FROM assuntos WHERE id = $assunto_id[0]") as $final)
            {
                print('<pre>');
                var_dump($final[0]);
                print('</pre>');
            }
        }
    }
}

print(queryDB('root', 'admin'));
```

O objetivo era:

1 - filtrar o produto de uma tabela, e pegar sua id;

2 - usar a id do respectivo produto para filtrar a id do assunto (que estava em outra tabela);

3 - usar a id do assunto para, enfim, mostrar o assunto (que também estava em outra tabela).

Com o script apresentado, eu consegui retornar os resultados esperados, mas como estou estudando boas práticas de código, penso que este script não está da maneira como deveria ser para executar as tarefas descritas. Eu mesmo chamei isso de `gambiarra`.

Então:

Qual seria a forma correta de fazer estas queries?

- como eu poderia ter feito no phpmyadmin/mysql
- como eu poderia ter feito o script (caso o atual seja redundante)
- como poderia ser feito a refatoração deste código.

Comment: poderia me dar alguma referência destes métodos? um link seria ótimo!, e como vc faria a refatoração deste código usando o JOIN?

Comment: Um bom começo => [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Comment: opa! vlw! eu até ja estava lendo http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html, mas acho os docs do mysql muito confusos! Me ajudou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . Primeiramente vamos ver como ficaria seus `SELECT's` se usarmos `JOIN`:

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.titulo, pt.id_assunto, as.titulo 
FROM produtos pr 
INNER JOIN produtos_tem_assuntos pt ON pr.id = pt.id_produto
INNER JOIN assuntos as ON pt.id_assunto =  as.id
WHERE pr.publicado > 0;
```

Um bom material de estudo para relacionamentos entre tabelas é o link abaixo:
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/

2 . Agora vamos aplicar o `SELECT` na função, deixando-a bem mais enxulta:

```
function queryDB($user, $pass)
{
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foobar', $user, $pass);

    $sql = "SELECT pr.id, pr.titulo, pt.id_assunto, as.titulo 
            FROM produtos pr 
            INNER JOIN produtos_tem_assuntos pt ON pr.id = pt.id_produto
            INNER JOIN assuntos as ON pt.id_assunto =  as.id
            WHERE pr.publicado > 0";

    $retorno = $connect->query($sql);

    // Testamos o retorno para não dar Warning
    if(count($retorno) > 0)
    {
        foreach( $retorno as $linha )
        {
            // Aqui fica sua lógica do que fazer com o retorno...
            print('<pre>');
            var_dump($linha);
            print('</pre>');
        }
    }
}
```

3 . Sobre refatorar o código, é sempre bom deixar a conexão em um arquivo separado, ou em uma variável global, evita você estar passando os dados de conexão em várias partes do código.

Na idéia abaixo, criamos um arquivo `connection.php` apenas para definirmos a conexão:

```
$user = "seu-usuario";
$pass = "sua-senha";
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foobar', $user, $pass);
```

Ai então nas paginas que vão ter acesso ao banco de dados, basta incluir a pagina `connection.php` e utilizar a variável `connect` para acesso ao banco:

```
include_once "connection.php";

function queryDB()
{
    // Pegamos a connecção global
    global $connect;

    $sql = "SELECT pr.id, pr.titulo, pt.id_assunto, as.titulo 
            FROM produtos pr 
            INNER JOIN produtos_tem_assuntos pt ON pr.id = pt.id_produto
            INNER JOIN assuntos as ON pt.id_assunto =  as.id
            WHERE pr.publicado > 0";

    $retorno = $connect->query($sql);

    // Testamos o retorno para não dar Warning
    if(count($retorno) > 0)
    {
        foreach( $retorno as $linha )
        {
            // Aqui fica sua lógica do que fazer com o retorno...
            print('<pre>');
            var_dump($linha);
            print('</pre>');
        }
    }
}
```

*** Obs: A solução apresentada não foi testada, pois eu não tinha a sua base de dados e tabelas criadas aqui... Caso apresente erros me informe que corrigimos.

Comment: perfeito! Obrigado :)